# why do i get Segmentation fault (core dumped) error here?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strrchr

while trying to regenerate the function strrchr i get this error, can someone help me understand this part?

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> char  *ft_strrchr(const char *s, int c)
> {
>   int i;
>   char *ptr;
>   ptr = NULL;
>   i = 0;
>   while (*s)
>   {
>       if (*(s + i) == (const char)c)
>       {
>           ptr = ((char*)(s + i));
>       }
>       ++i;
>   }
>   return (ptr);
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     const char *tx = "test a test a test";
>     int a = 'a';
>     char *ptr = ft_strrchr(tx,a);
>     printf("%c",*ptr);
>
>     return 0;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: `char ptr;` , do you mean `char *ptr;`?

Comment: `while (*s)` is an infinite loop since `s` never changes. Presumably that means `i` grows forever and you run off the end of the string into no mans land.

Comment: Changing it to `while (*(s + i))` will fix the problem mentioned by @RetiredNinja above. Note that the real `strrchr` also allows you to search for the character `'\0'` which will always be at the end of the null-terminated source string. Your version doesn't support that currently.